# Froala WYISWYG editor not showing the toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, froala

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('textarea#froala-editor').froalaEditor({
            toolbarInline: false,
            toolbarButtons: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', '-', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL'],
            toolbarVisibleWithoutSelection: true
         })
     });
</script>
```

It is just appearing the textarea without the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

i believe if you remove the toolbarInline and toolbarVisibleWithoutSelection options, you will be ok.

also, there is a function selector.froalaEditor('toolbar.show')